# xAxis.breaks Gantt hightchart not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I'm trying to hide holidays and sundays from a gantt with highcharts js

I have the following code in which I go through an array where the holidays and Sundays are

```
JS

breaks: diasFestivos.map(function(fecha) {
    return {
    from: new Date(fecha).setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0),
    to: new Date(fecha).setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999),
    breakSize: 0,
};
})
```

I also tried this way but the end result is the same

```
JS

breaks: diasFestivos.map(function(fecha) {
    return {
    from: new Date(fecha).getTime(),
    to: new Date(fecha).getTime(),
    breakSize: 0,
};
})
```

But more dates are hidden in the gantt than I have in my non-working days arrangement. Why does this happen?.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBrGT.png)

As I show in the image, more days should appear between those dates

Comment: Hi @carlos maya, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? Breaks seem to work fine in Gantt, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uc32bqnr/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek this is my code https://jsfiddle.net/carmaro/g2mvq8b4/22/
Here I try to hide 2023-08-12, but it doesn't work. In the example I also run an array with all the days but I get an error when executed

Comment: To hide the whole day, you need to set different `from` and `to` dates. For example: `from: Date.UTC(2023, 7, 12), to: Date.UTC(2023, 7, 13),`. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4tegkas9/